# Submitting Apple Watch App getting "Apple Watch not supported"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I made an Apple Watch supported app but when I try to archive the app it says "Apple Watch Not Supported" has anyone run into this problem?

Comment: Can you please show the error? Also, explain what you did so far.

Comment: I think we can't upload apps with iWatch support till Aprl24.. "Starting April 24, you will be able to deliver innovative new experiences to your customers on their wrist" https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/